# How can I ask for users to input a password before downloading a autogenerated file from my server?

Tags: php, html, apache

So, i have the following situation:
I want users to enter the page **www.server.com/download.php**, get asked for a username and password, then if valid the server will generate a file *file.csv* in the webroot and redirect the user to it (make him download the file).
Another important detail is that this task should be easy to do with **wget** or **curl** or other automated download tool.
I already have the sistem working, i can **wget** *www.server.com/download.php* and i get *file.csv*!
The problem is that *file.csv* is sitting on the webroot and anyone can download it by accessing it directly, and anyone can fire *download.php*.

Any sugestions are welcome!

Comment: If you don't need fancy password management, you CAN have apache pw-protect the download script with a plain-jane http basic auth password prompt. And then move the .csv file out of your webroot so it's ONLY accessible via the download.php script.

Comment: Marc is right, just use an .htpsswd file.

Comment: using .htpsasswd is extremly unsafe compare to hashed out password stored in DB or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Put your download file in a protected directory that is only accessible if a server side user-is-authenticated flag is set to true.  Put your authentication form and an error page in a public directory.  Reroute any unauthenticated traffic that tries to access the protected directory to the error page

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you authenticate the user with php and then direct him to file.csv @ webroot, which in fact would be a script (rewrited by htaccess) that will check if the user is authenticated and if he is, then he will get *his* file. In that case all files can be stored anywhere, say in /files/ folder under any name you want.